# ASP.NET Web Api 2 post request From Uri and From Body

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

I have an ASP.NET Web Api 2 endpoint that is meant to be consumed by diffelerent clients. The endpoint should accept posted data from body as well as from Uri.
So my question is if it's possible for my POST action to support both type of requests and have the posted data mapped in the POST action?

My solution to the problem is to have exposed two endpoints - one supporting each scenario (see my code below), but I would rather have only one endpoint that I can give to all the clients. How is it possible?

```
// The Controller Action when data is posted in the Uri:

// POST: api/PostUri
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("PostUri")]
public Result Post([FromUri]Data data)
{
   // Do something..
}

// The Controller Action when request is posted with data in the Body:

// POST: api/MyController/PostBody
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("PostBody")]
public Result PostBody(Data data)
{
   return Post(data);
}
```

Comment: Reference [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able solve it by having my `Controller` `Action` taking two parameters. Both parameters of my Data type - one with `[FromUri]` Attribute and one without:

```C#
public Result Post([FromUri]Data fromUri, Data fromBody)
{
    // Check fromUri and its properties
    // Check fromBody and its properties
    ...

}
```

If the `Request` of data is placed in the body, the data will be bind to `fromBody` parameter. If the `Request` data is in the URI then they will be bind to `fromUri` parameter using the `[FromUri]` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve your goal with custom implementation of `HttpParameterBinding`. Here is working example of such binder:

```
public class UriOrBodyParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    private readonly HttpParameterDescriptor paramDescriptor;

    public UriOrBodyParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor) : base(descriptor)
    {
        paramDescriptor = descriptor;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpParameterBinding binding = actionContext.Request.Content.Headers.ContentLength > 0
            ? new FromBodyAttribute().GetBinding(paramDescriptor)
            : new FromUriAttribute().GetBinding(paramDescriptor);

        await binding.ExecuteBindingAsync(metadataProvider, actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

We check `Content-Length` HTTP header to find out whether request contains http body. If yes, we bind the model from the body. Otherwise the model is bind from the Url.

You should also add custom attribute for marking action parameters for which this custom binder would be used:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public sealed class FromUriOrBodyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Here is binder registration that should be added to `WebApiConfig.Register()` method. We check whether action parameter is marked with `FromUriOrBodyAttribute` and use our custom binder in this case:

```
config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, paramDesc =>
{
    if (paramDesc.GetCustomAttributes<FromUriOrBodyAttribute>().Any())
    {
        return new UriOrBodyParameterBinding(paramDesc);
    }

    return null;
});
```

Now you could have one Post action that will bind the model from request body or Url:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromUriOrBody] Data data)
{
    //  ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to me like a lot of work for a simpel task!

Comment: Binding model from both body and Uri parameters is not a very common task. That's why ASP.NET framework does not support it out of the box. However it is flexible enough and provides extensibility points for making it possible, as I demonstrated. As regards amount of the code required for it - it doesn't seem too complex and is based on existing binders. It's up to you whether to use it, but I doubt that it's possible to do it with less efforts.